# Redeeming a PSN dlc code

Tags: ps-vita

So recently I stopped playing on my vita... ( What a mistake buying that thing).
I still have a PlayStation All Stars code for the online features.
Is there  a way to find out if the code still works without redeeming it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll be able to cancel before redeeming. Once you enter the code there'll be a screen having you confirm your order/purchase, if the code is invalid you'll just get an error screen.